# Hard problem mechanical advantage

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, physics

Figure shows a tensioning device used to tighten the rear stay of
the mast of a sailboat. The block and tackle pulls down a rigid bar with two
rollers that squeeze together the two branches of the split rear stay. If the
angles are as given in the figure, what is the mechanical advantage?

[image]

I am tryign to find the distance from the pivot to  F' then divide by the distance to F

$$D_f = 72.5cos \theta$$
$$D_f' = 75cos \theta $$

$$3\frac{D_f}{D_f'} = 2.9 $$

I multiply by three because there is three pulleys in the middle

however I get the wrong answer the answer should be around 34.6 what did I get wrong?

update: I was trying:

$$7\frac{72.5}{15} = 33.8$$

wich is getting close to the answer, but not exactly. where 7 is the number of tensions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the key question when figuring out mechanical advantage is figuring out the ratio of how much the input rope moves vs. how much the output moves. Then since the work in is the work out, that gives the ratio of the forces.

The block and tackle just gives a ratio of 4 to the rope - note that it’s not the expected 3 since the rope attaches to the moving pulley. If you kept the initial rope still and pulled the rigid bar, count the number of rolls which would need to stretch.

In the left part of the diagram, the main question is what happens as the rigid bar moves. The location of the bar moves up, so more rope gets pulled into the bottom triangle under the rigid bar as that hypotenuse lengthens. On the other, that means there’s less rope in the top triangle, so that triangle shrinks.

The top string makes an angle of $90-35/2=72.5$ degrees with the horizontal. The bottom string is 15 degrees shallower, so 57.5 degrees.  When the height of the rigid bar increases by a bit, the hypotenuse of the bottom triangle increases by $\sin(57.5 ^\circ)$.  When the top string’s hypotenuse decreases by $\sin(57.5^\circ)$, the top triangle’s height decreases by $\sin(57.5 ^\circ )/\sin(72.5 ^\circ)$. The overall height of the diagram (and so the location of the output) is the sun of the heights of the two triangles, so since moving the down rigid bar by 1 moves the upper triangle higher by $\sin(57.5 ^\circ )/\sin(72.5 ^\circ)$, it moves the final location by $1-\sin(57.5 ^\circ )/\sin(72.5 ^\circ)$

This means that the total height and so the distance moves by the output is $1-\sin(57.5^\circ)/\sin(72.5 ^\circ )$ times as much as the rigid bar’s movement which due to the block and tackle is $1/4$ times as much as the entire structure’s input movement. This gives a total mechanical advantage of $1/(1/4 \cdot (1-\sin(57.5 ^\circ)/\sin(72.5 ^\circ))) = 34.6$

Comment: why did you put 1 -sin57.5, and also why are you diving with the MA I think you should multiply, also the result of your last equation gives me 72.89?

Comment: The 1-sin/sin expression is because the final location is the location of the rigid bar plus the height of the top triangle. When you decrease the final bar (1) you increase the height of the triangle (-sin/sin expression) and you need to add those two terms. I did multiply the 1/4 by the sin expression to get the ratio of input to output. Then I took the inverse since MA is the other way.

Comment: A more rigorous way might be to write out the length of the rope as. a function of the rigid bar’s location and the total height of the diagram and take a derivative. You can then simplify the resulting ratios in that equation to get the same sin formulas as above.

Comment: The answer still gives me around 70.36??? from your last equation

Comment: Whoops, wrong order in the last equation. Though not sure how you get 70.36.